# How to use currencyFormatter with a decimal

Tags: ios, xcode, core-data, swift3, currency-formatting

I'm trying to take a decimal I'm storing in CoreData and run it through the currency formatter in Swift 3. Here is what I'm trying to use:

```
var currencyFormatter = NumberFormatter()
currencyFormatter.usesGroupingSeparator = true
currencyFormatter.numberStyle = NumberFormatter.Style.currency
// localize to your grouping and decimal separator
currencyFormatter.locale = NSLocale.current
var priceString = currencyFormatter.stringFromNumber(NSNumber(totalAmount))
```

Where totalAmount is the decimal I'm using for CoreData.

But . I get this error when trying to convert my decimal to a NSNumber()

`Argument labels '(_:)' do not match any available overloads`

Comment: use `string(from:)` or `string(for:)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`stringFromNumber` got renamed to `string(from:)`, e.g.

```
var priceString = currencyFormatter.string(from: NSNumber(totalAmount))
```

but you don't have to convert to `NSNumber`

```
var priceString = currencyFormatter.string(for: totalAmount)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have something like:

```
class YourClass: UIViewController {
  static let priceFormatter: NumberFormatter = {
    let formatter = NumberFormatter()

    formatter.formatterBehavior = .behavior10_4
    formatter.numberStyle = .currency

    return formatter
  }()
}
```

Usage:

```
yourLabel.text = YourClass.priceFormatter.string(from: totalAmount)
```